Is the derived category of sheaves localised at pointwise homotopy equivalences locally small?
In order to define the cup and cross products in sheaf cohomology, Iversen makes computations in an intermediate derived category. If $K(X;k)$ is the triangulated category of cochain complexes of sheaves of $k$-modules on the space $X$, we put $G^+(X;k)$ to be the localisation of $K^+(X;k)$ at the null system of pointwise contractible complexes; complexes $\mathcal{F}^\bullet$ satisfying $\forall x\in X$, the complex of stalks $\mathcal{F}^\bullet_x$ is a contractible complex of $k$-modules in the typical sense. This is a true Verdier quotient, is triangulated and saturated with calculus of fractions and all that good stuff.
He doesn't name this object, and attempts to find reference to it outside of his book "Cohomology of Sheaves" have failed. Part of my question is: is this named, well-known, studied? References (which aren't of the "unpublished note" type) would be appreciated.
The other part; is it locally small? Does it "exist"? I don't normally care about this sort of thing but it feels like it should be true and it would surely be nice, since the full derived category $D(X)$ is locally small, but I'm struggling to copy over the proof $D(X)$ is locally small to a proof $G^+(X;k)$ is locally small. Using the Godement resolution and making it a double complex and totalising in the obvious ways allows you to take any bounded below $\mathcal{F}^\bullet$ and inject it into a canonical complex $T\mathcal{F}^\bullet$, functorial in $\mathcal{F}^\bullet$, such that $\mathcal{F}^\bullet\hookrightarrow T\mathcal{F}^\bullet$ is a pointwise homotopy equivalence. The only way I know how to check a derived category "exists" and is locally small is to check what Weibel calls local smallness of the morphisms-to-be-inverted (on the right or the left, it matters not) which are here the pointwise homotopy equivalences.
So this becomes the question: given a fixed complex $\mathcal{F}^\bullet$, is there a set $J$ of pointwise homotopy equivalences $\mathcal{F}^\bullet\to\mathcal{G}^\bullet$ such that an arbitrary pointwise homotopy equivalence $\mathcal{F}^\bullet\to\mathcal{H}^\bullet$ (of bounded below complexes) necessarily admits a map $\mathcal{H}^\bullet\to\mathcal{G}^\bullet$, some $\mathcal{G}^\bullet$, so that the composite $\mathcal{F}^\bullet\to\mathcal{G}^\bullet$ is in $J$?
When handling the analogous question for quasiisomorphisms (but looking on the left, because it's easier) the proof is essentially "fix a big cardinal $\kappa$ and for any quasiisomorphism $\mathcal{H}^\bullet\to\mathcal{F}^\bullet$ you can find a complex of subsheaves which is bounded by $\kappa$ in some sense, by choosing generators in cohomology at each stalk etc. etc." and it's not too hard. It clearly can be done. But I have no idea what the analogue of "choosing generating cohomology classes per stalk" would be if we want to engineer a pointwise homotopy equivalence, I suppose dually by taking some kind of quotient of $\mathcal{H}$. Or maybe I'm foolish and working on the left is better but that situation is even more unclear since it contravenes the direction $\mathcal{F}^\bullet\hookrightarrow T\mathcal{F}^\bullet$.
I've toyed with the idea of taking some set of those "projective" resolutions of sheaves, through sheaves of the form $\bigoplus j_\ast\widetilde{k}$ as $j$ ranges through open embeddings $U\hookrightarrow X$, since we could try the subcomplex-admitting-quasiisomorphisms trick and recall (looking at each stalk) that a quasiisomorphism between bounded below cochain complexes of projectives is a homotopy equivalence (but I couldn't finish that idea in a satisfactory way).

I notice in Iversen's text it is implicitly shown that if $D$ is a sheaf with $\mathsf{Ext}^\bullet_k(D,S)=0$ for all flabby sheaves $S$, in positive degree, then the mapping group $G^+(X;k)(D,\mathcal{F}^\bullet)$ is a small set for any complex $\mathcal{F}^\bullet$. That's encouraging but I'm not sure how to improve it
